# Field initializer error with DBContext constructor when connection string has been passed to the repository constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor, dbcontext

I am building a multi-tenanted application. The code is shared but each client has a different database. I have code that determines the specific client's database connection string (based on an API key they are using).

I want to initialise the context using this connection string.

I approached this by passing the string to the repository constructor in the hope I could then reuse it for the context constructor but I am getting the error:

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property...
```

when I attempt to initialize an Entity Framework database context using a connection string that I have previously passed into the Repository constructor.

I have researched and understand the error (you can't initialize one instance member using an other instance member, as it may not be available at that time) but I am unsure how to work my way around it.

What I am trying to achieve is self-evident from the code:

```
public class GlobalCompanyRepository : IGlobalCompanyRepository
{
    private readonly string _dbConnectionString;

    public GlobalCompanyRepository(string dbConnectionString)
    {
        _dbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
    }

    public IntrinsicDbContext dbContext = new IntrinsicDbContext(_dbConnectionString);
    public void Add(GlobalCompany entity)
    {
        dbContext.GlobalCompanies.Add(entity);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the dbContext in the constructor when _dbConnectingString has a value:

```
public class GlobalCompanyRepository : IGlobalCompanyRepository
{
    private readonly string _dbConnectionString;

    public GlobalCompanyRepository(string dbConnectionString)
    {
        _dbConnectionString = dbConnectionString;
        dbContext = new IntrinsicDbContext(_dbConnectionString);
    }

    public IntrinsicDbContext dbContext;
    public void Add(GlobalCompany entity)
    {
        dbContext.GlobalCompanies.Add(entity);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to initialize your field dbContext

```
public IntrinsicDbContext dbContext = new   IntrinsicDbContext(_dbConnectionString);
```

Before `_dbConnectionString` has been given a value.

You can move the initialization into the constructor.